# Resizing image to fit Ui Image View in xcode storyboard

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I am trying to fit an image to fit the entire of the Ui Image View. I want to do this because I want to round my image and it does not work because the image is smaller than the entire view. So rounding it rounds the outside of the image and is not visible. I have tried to add constraints but that does not seem to have workout.

Here is an image of what I am trying to do:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIGow.png

The problem images:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGDyx.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3RVZ.png

Comment: You need to add constraints to your `UIImageView` to fill the view.

Comment: @DonMag sadly, that did not solve it.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're showing. Are you using a custom `@IBDesignable` image view to get the rounded corners?

Comment: "IBOutlet weak var SHOPS: UIImageView!" I have used this method to round the corners. But for some reason it does not seem to work at all. instead the image is saler and the white space is rounded but the image itself is not rounded. @DonMag

Comment: What do you have selected for the image view's `Content Mode`? To have the image fill the image view, it should be set to either `Scale To Fill` or `Aspect Fill`

Comment: I have tried both just now but it does not seem to work. @DonMag

Comment: Hmmm? The new screen-caps you posted show the image filling the view. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Yes but No at the same time as you can see the image is not rounded and when I highlight it the borders are rounded but not the image on its own. As the white border is rounded. I will add a reference picture of how it shall look. @DonMag

Answer (score 0):

OK - the problem is that you don't understand the Xcode interface.

When you have added a `UIImageView`, set its image, and then select it, you see this:

[image]

If you click the image view again, Xcode shows an additional "highlight" outline:

[image]

That has nothing to do with how it will look when you run your app.

Regarding the screen-cap from the video you are watching... You either didn't notice, or forgot, two things:

1. it's a tutorial for SwiftUI - the screen-caps you've posted for what you're trying to do is from a UIKit based app.
2. at 17:20 of **Part 1** of that series, the author explains how he is setting the corner radius.

To get what you want with UIKit, you need to write some code to give the image view rounded corners. To have it show up at design-time, you need to use an `@IBDesignable` image view subclass.

Here's a ***very*** basic example:

```
@IBDesignable
class RoundedImageView: UIImageView {
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        layer.cornerRadius = 20
    }
    
}
```

If you set the Custom Class of your image view to `RoundedImageView`, and then either select either `Editor -> Refresh All Views` or have `Editor -> Automatically Refresh Designable Views` checked, you'll see this:

[image]

Comment: Hey, Yes I noticed form the beginning but My layout was the only thing that was inspired that is why that picture was given in the question. I was aware that he was not using storyboard.

Comment: I also dont really understand how the code works as it does not specify the image in any sort of way.

Comment: @Kaushik - The tutorial video you watched used SwiftUI, and the view has a `.cornerRadius(20)` property. When *not* using SwiftUI, **your code** has to set the corner radius somewhere. Using a custom `@IBDesignable` class let's you see the result of that code in Storyboard. Search for some tutorials on `@IBDesignable` to get a better understanding -- it's far too much for a single answer here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Kaushik - the **main point** of my answer was explaining what you *thought* you were seeing when selecting your image view (the rounded highlight).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention why I was confused with the highlighting and also getting errors like setvalue error. I used "@IBOutlet weak var SHOPS: UIImageView! SHOPS.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        SHOPS.layer.masksToBounds = true" as per the video it should have worked but I hept on getting errors like set value undefined key when I run and do not understand the reason. I have searched it up and still did not work out.

Comment: @Kaushik - *"set value undefined key"* ... ok, that's a ***completely*** different topic. It means you do not have your image view correctly connected to your `@IBOutlet`. Make sure your view controller class is set to the class in your code... make sure Xcode shows the connection... try going through a few "learning the basics" tutorials.